# Is there a way to automate webscraping (copy and paste) of images in R?

Tags: r, image, web-scraping

If you type in a city on Google Maps, it comes up with a faint red boundary. If you right click on the map, the first entry is latitude and longitude coordinates. An example is below (London, UK):

[image]

What I'd like to do is copy and paste the coordinates to a .csv file, then go back to the map in the web browser, adjust the cursor so that it moves 0.1 kilometres (to scale), and repeat the process, until I have a list of longitude and latitude coordinates of the whole map on screen, each being 0.1 kilometres apart.

So for instance, if this screen had 1500 kilometres in it, I'd want a list of 15,000 longitude/latitude pairs (because there are 10 pairs per kilometre).

I'd appreciate guidance on where to start with this and whether it is possible!

Answer (score 1):

Not so clear what is your main intention.
Maybe you can achieve it without any Google stuff...
For example public datasets, [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) etc.
It depends on the details of your/your customer's requirements.

Or at least consider the followings:

- Do you have any permission for this method? (see **2.Prohibited Conduct of** [Google Maps/Google Earth Additional Terms of Service](https://www.google.com/help/terms_maps/))
- What about legal Google Maps APIs/services?
  https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/

Btw. Google as scraping company does not like scraping on their surfaces :)
For example scraping Google Search results...